# Data.frame from list of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

A rather simple answer.

Given a named named json-like `list` of `data.frame` rows, how would one transform this into a proper `data.frame` in a **concise** manner while keeping the column classes and row names intact.

```
df_list <- lapply(1:10, function(x)list(a = 1, b = 'hello', c = 3 - 1i))
names(df_list) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

desired result

```
data.frame(a = rep(1, 10), b = rep('hello', 10), c = rep(3 - 1i, 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = df_list) %>% 
      unnest_wider(c(col1))
```

---

Or with `bind_rows`

```
bind_rows(df_list)
```

Or with `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(df_list)
```