# Data.frame from nested list of rows, with columns of class list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

Very similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62121791/10782538).

Given a named `list` where each element represents a row in a `data.frame` one element which may be a `list` or similar class such as `data.frame` how can this be transformed into a proper `data.frame`-like object in a **concise** manner

## Example

```
library(data.table)
df_list <- lapply(1:10, function(x)list(a = 1, b = 'hello', 
                                        c = 3 - 1i, 
                                        d = data.table(e = 1:3, 
                                                       f = LETTERS[1:3])))
names(df_list) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

## Expected output

May be exchanged for a `data.table` object with a `rownames` column or a `data.frame`.

```
d <- lapply(1:10, function(x)data.table(e = 1:3, f = LETTERS[1:3]))
df <- tibble(a = rep(1, 10), b = rep('hello', 10), c = rep(3 - 1i, 10), d = d)
df$rownames <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

## Note:

`data.table::rbindlist(df_list, fill = TRUE)` and `dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)` failed in their raw form.

Comment: Your example is `d = ` is not complete

Comment: Not clear because the previous example wwas working fine for me

Comment: Interesting. It didn't copy my entire D. will be updated on a moment.

Comment: DId you menat your input as `df_list <- lapply(1:10, function(x)list(a = 1, b = 'hello', c = 3 - 1i, d = data.table(e = 1:3, f = LETTERS[1:3])))`

Comment: Indeed. It seems some parts of the copy-paste was cut-off during action (that one is new to me on SO). Should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
tibble(col1 = df_list, rn = names(col1)) %>% 
             unnest_wider(c(col1))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#       a b     c     d                        rn   
#   <dbl> <chr> <cpl> <list>                   <chr>
# 1     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> A    
# 2     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> B    
# 3     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> C    
# 4     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> D    
# 5     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> E    
# 6     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> F    
# 7     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> G    
# 8     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> H    
# 9     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> I    
#10     1 hello 3-1i  <data.table[,2] [3 × 2]> J
```

---

Or if we want to use `data.table`, we can loop over the `list`, then convert the atomic elements to `data.table` and create a column with the non-atomic, and then use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(df_list, function(x)  {
    i1 <- sapply(x, is.data.table)
     as.data.table(x[!i1])[, names(x)[i1] := x[i1]]
    }), idcol= 'rn')
#    rn a     b    c            d
# 1:  A 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 2:  B 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 3:  C 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 4:  D 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 5:  E 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 6:  F 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 7:  G 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 8:  H 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
# 9:  I 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
#10:  J 1 hello 3-1i <data.table>
```